# How do I keep exact text formatting when using a data validation dropdown list in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, data-validation

I have a column that contains a bold number and a non-bold text part. I want to use this information as a drop-down selection list, but it currently isn't letting me keep the bold formatting on only the number part.

For instance "**14250** House" becomes "14250 House" when copied.

The digits are exactly 5, the word(s) afterward is of undetermined length, approximately 5 to 10 letters and spaces.

Is there an option somewhere to fix this or maybe a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Bold in drop-down]

It would not be possible to have a drop-down list with a mixture of plain and bold text ... but using a particular encoding it will be possible. The formula is quite complex, take it apart function by function to understand it.

```
=ifna(REGEXREPLACE(A2,text(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\d+"),"0"),join("",index(char(code(split(RegexReplace(TEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\d+"),"0"), "(.)", "$1 ")," "))+120734)))))
```

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BjRpjKcPnsEoCq_zicmdQRqCqfQjgnBYZdOiIBUkUww/edit?usp=sharing) the test sheet

Comment: Another option is to use Google Apps Script and the edit trigger to apply the format after selecting the dropdown value. *Your mileage might vary*. :)